# Shower drain height for curbless tile shower

Tags: plumbing, concrete, shower, remodeling

I want to do floor tiles for the shower and it must be curbless.
It is the basement and has concrete foundation.

Right now the drain I bought is sticking up 3" from the concrete floor:

[image]

This is the model I bought:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-Oatey-PVC-Shower-Drain-with-Square-4-3-16-in-Stainless-Steel-Strainer-423112/305248423

Oatey PVC Shower Drain with Square 4-3/16 in. Stainless Steel Strainer

[image]

So my question is: **How to lower the drain height for curbless shower?**

If the shower flooring has curb then it is flexible because I can raise the base. But in this case I don't want to raise the whole floor.

I am thinking of these options:

1. Break the concrete entirely around the drain and change a new drain that is lower.
2. Cut the top part of the drain pipe by 1.5" and also 1.5" of the drain piece. That will make the whole thing near flush to the concrete foundation. But the problem is (I faced in the past) that the pipe is in this shape:

> /   \

Meaning the top doesn't have same diameter from the diameter 1.5" away.
So in this case: **How to join the 2 pieces together?**

Also I am thinking that I have to carve off about 1.5" off around the shower base anyways, according to this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7RXFugbSE

If that is the case, look like this will be some concrete mess job. Then I mean leaning toward **Option 1** above.

Thought?

**UPDATE 1**

I planned to get this drain kit

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DN6CFYF?pf_rd_p=183f5289-9dc0-416f-942e-e8f213ef368b&pf_rd_r=JAPWGGX9RR0R6231QEDN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DN6CFYF)

[https://www.amazon.com/Neodrain-2-Inch-Shower-Rubber-Installation/dp/B06XSQF1VR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XSQF1VR)

Basically the setup will look like this

[image]

The kit itself will add at least 3" on top of the pipe. So to be safe I am thinking about **pushing the drain pipe down 4"**.

Then I also need to grind and **take out 3" of concrete in the shower base**.

Does it sound about right? It is a messy job but could be done in one day with concrete tool rental from Home Improvement store...

Comment: This is a big job. Question: Does it have to be curbless? If it’s in regard to wheelchair access or another mobility issue, there are easier options.

Comment: Yeah over the years, we think curbless is the best. Also having travel to many Asian countries, lots of new houses and hotels are curbless. We love it. What other ideas you have?

Comment: The issue is your concrete floor. To go curbless, you have to go below the current height of the floor. I built and remodeled bathrooms as a business for over ten years and in order to create a great shower that adds to the value of your home, building codes must be followed to the letter. The drain you now have is going to require a much deeper hole. A large shower with a curbed showerpan and one open side would be easier to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with @M.Mat. It does not look like you've lowered the floor. For curbless you must lower the floor so it can be floated to provide slope to the drain, which will require your entire drain assembly (trap arm, trap, and shower drain) to be much lower. You're gonna need to get real good at bustin out concrete...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I can lower the floor around the shower base. That is do-able and could be a messy job but it's OK. I think having this curbless is important.